# How can I convert a 3D list into a 2D list in python?

Tags: python, list

This is the code that I have:

```
[[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
```

How can I change it into:

```
[[3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

?

Comment: so much one could say about this question, but for starters, nested lists are not referred to by "nD" - "a list of lists of lists" would suffice at the least

Comment: When dealing with lists in *any* nontrivial way, *always* use numpy.

Comment: @o11c Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to flatten a single level of the input list, try this solution using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
[e for sl in lst for e in sl]
=> [[3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[3],[4]],[[5],[6]],[[7],[8]]])
b = a.reshape(6,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A uncompressed or long way:

```
l3d = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
l2d = []
for e1 in l3d:
   for e2 in e1:
      l2d.append(e2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Provided list
lst = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]

# To do this we are going to import chain from itertools
from itertools import chain

final = list(chain(*lst))

print(final)  # Output: [[3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```