# How to convert a 2 dimensional Python list to a 3 dimensional list?

Tags: python

If I have a Python list:

```
my_list = [['Apples',10],['Bananas',15],['Oranges',2]]
```

... how can I convert it to a 3 dimensional list to:

```
my_list = [['Apples',10,0],['Bananas',15,0],['Oranges',2,0]]
```

This is a normal Python list (without using numpy).

Comment: You want 3rd element to be always zero?

Comment: ``[x + [0] for x in my_list]`` ?

Comment: Is that 3 dimension? you could try looping through first list and `append` to each list element

Comment: you can find your answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910827/how-can-i-convert-a-3d-list-into-a-2d-list-in-python

Comment: @kuro Yep, I want the third element to always be zero.

Comment: Susanath has given you the answer, see the comment @slantalpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [x.append(0) for x in my_list]
```

or as commented by @Sushanth

`[x+[0] for x in my_list]`

Answer (score 4):

Fancy and readable approach:

```
my_list = [['Apples',10],['Bananas',15],['Oranges',2]]

for item in my_list: item.append(0)  # loop through each element

print(my_list) # output: [['Apples', 10, 0], ['Bananas', 15, 0], ['Oranges', 2, 0]]
```